# how to know number of available reducer slots capacity in yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I am moving from Hadoop 1.0 to YARN enable cluster. While running the adhoc job in 1.0  we used to specify number of reducer based on availability reported in Job tracker  for faster processing . Now in YARN 'all application'  web link we do not see any such column/info about availability  . Is there any configuration file or in the web link we can get this info?

Answer (score 1):

There is no more slot in Yarn.

Instead, verything depends on the amount of memory in use/demande. You can config the yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores to control the task.

More info about config file example here:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: Thanks for response , but then how the backward compatibility works in terms of specifying the number of reducer from command line ? I am really puzzled with this YARN stuff :)